# Applescript and "starts with" operator

Tags: list, applescript, startswith

Is there a way to check (in applescript) if a list (or block of html text) `starts with` any number of values.

Example (checking for a single value)

```
if {foobar starts with "<p>"} then
    -- do something awesome here
end if
```

except i would like to pass multiple values to check `<p>` or `<h1>` or `<em>`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
on startswith(txt, l)
    repeat with v in l
        if txt starts with v then return true
    end repeat
    false
end startswith

startswith("abc", {"a", "d", "e"}) -- true
```

Comment: works great on its own Lri, but how can i implement it within this script. I'm not fluent in applescript at all. Heres a link to it on pastebin http://pastebin.com/mS3wyYQX

Comment: @VicePrez That would need to be another question. Here's something similar though: [wrap_lines_with_tag.applescript](http://cs.helsinki.fi/u/lranta/pastebin/wrap_lines_with_tag.applescript)

Comment: thanks lri, ill try to work with one you gave me, if it doesnt work out ill post another question related to the one i currently have. +1

Answer (score 7):

If you want to stay within the 'English' style of AppleScript, although longer than the example above, you can just do this:

```
if {foobar starts with "hello" or foobar starts with "goodbye"} then
```

A full example would be:

```
set foobar to "hello dude"
if {foobar starts with "hello" or foobar starts with "goodbye"} then
    display dialog "found"
end if
```

That will be true even if you change:

```
set foobar to "hello dude"
```

to:

```
set foobar to "goodbye dude"
```

Comment: interesting info. i posted another question related to this problem in another page. @Lri was kind enough to create a tailor fit solution to the problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932752/applescript-wrap-lines-with-html-tags-and-marsedit-app-script-problem)